# Excel 2010 VBA - How to use text with assigned font properties in MSGBOX, DEBUG.PRINT, etc

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, fonts

I have a worksheet with cells that have been assigned font properties in a macro, e.g. color.

I want to DEBUG.PRINT a selected cell (or use it to provide the PROMPT or TITLE in a MSGBOX) showing all its font properties.

Although the worksheet displays and PRINTs the values in full color correctly, DEBUG.PRINT and MSGBOX display only the ASCII text in standard colors and fonts. How do I keep the font properties in such contexts?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.

Nor debug.print nor MSGBox support formatting.

What you need to do is create a custom form, and program the changes in.

For example:

```
form_messagebox.show

form_messagebox.text1.caption = "string"
form_messagebox.text1.font = font settings
```

etc...

Comment: Just as well to know that; it will save me a lot of time trying to do the impossible. So many thanks for your prompt information.

Comment: @hershmab Please accept this answer then, so others know you no longer need help.